# Concern with whirlpool tub pump drainage

Tags: plumbing, drain, pipe, drainage, pump

I am having a whirlpool tub installed by a plumber. [This](https://americh.com/dropindetails.php?product_id=447) is the tub. We purchased it with an upgraded pump, specifically [this one](http://www.syllent.com/super-syllent-series/). It came from the factory looking like this:

[image]

The pump is mounted at one end of the tub, with the pump's intake located higher than the tub's suction inlet (this is so that inlet can be a drain for the pump after the bath).

Our installation box was very tight, and the pump needed to be moved to one of the long sides of the tub. The mfr said this is ok, but noted the height difference requirement that I allude to above. The plumber first installed it with the intake **lower** than the tub's suction inlet, which I took issue with, because I did not want old bathwater stagnating in the lines (between the pump and the tub's suction inlet) and unable to drain. After much arguing I eventually convinced the plumber to reinstall the pump a few inches higher, and now I am content that its intake is higher than the tub's suction inlet (barely... like 0.5"). But now I realize a new potential issue. The plumber did not install a straight route of pipe between those two points. Specifically, the pipe goes straight up for several inches just out of pump's intake. From there, it continues downhill all the way to the tub's suction inlet. The vertical section:

[image]

and a more simplistic system diagram:

[image]

So, now I am **still** concerned that there will be stagnant water in the system after a bath (specifically in the vertical section of the blue pipe in the image above, and in the pump itself). About the only way I can imagine this will still be ok is if a siphoning effect helps to empty the vertical pipe and the pump. The rest of the drain pipe (downstream from the vertical section) is much longer than that section, so hopefully this bodes well for any hypothetical siphoning effect? If not, I'm going to have to ask this plumber to reseat the tub a third time, and he is not going to be happy.

Comment: It makes everyone's life much easier when the images are embeded - saves a lot of clicking around.

Comment: When typing up your post, simply drag the pics into the edit box. Or, click the "sun & mountain" icon and follow the directions there for embedding.